# Change button style programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to draw material design Flat Button on android, for that i made this renderer:

```
public class NativeFlatButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var oldElement = e.OldElement as NativeFlatButton;

        if (oldElement != null)
        {
        }

        var newElement = e.NewElement as NativeFlatButton;
        if (newElement != null)
        {
            Control.SetBackgroundResource(Android.Resource.Style.WidgetMaterialButtonBorderless);
        }
    }
}
```

and it throws **Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1030259**
when i change to

```
if (newElement != null)
{
   var button = new AppCompatButton(Context, null, Android.Resource.Style.WidgetMaterialButtonBorderlessColored);
   SetNativeControl(button);
}
```

its drawing but without commands etc. **So how i can draw Flat Button with renderer on android?**

Answer (score 0):

That was quiet easy. Here is the ButtonRenderer method that creates native control:

```
protected override Android.Widget.Button CreateNativeControl()
{
   return new Android.Widget.Button(this.Context);
}
```

So i only need to override it and there is my complete renderer:

```
public class NativeFlatButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override Android.Widget.Button CreateNativeControl()
    {
        var button = new AppCompatButton(Context, null, Android.Resource.Style.WidgetMaterialButtonBorderlessColored);
        return button;
    }
}
```